# Multiple cameras rejecting their own batteries

Tags: canon, battery, panasonic-lumix

I don't use my cameras as often since 2020 and lockdowns... and sometime when I pull them out of the bag, I get surprises... (like "Please set the date"...)

Yesterday both of these happened:

- **Panasonic GH5s** rejected the battery that came with it (brand new camera some years ago). The camera stays on for a short time then shows message "This battery cannot be used.", then shuts down. I had to use an older battery that came with an older Panasonic GH4 (but the has shorter autonomy I think).
- **Canon 5D Mark IV** was on and suddenly showed messages like "Battery communication error", "This battery may be counterfeit.", "OK", shut down. I use the same set of 3 batteries since years (2016 I think). One of them came with the 5D Mark IV and the other two were purchased separately as genuine Canon batteries and never caused any trouble.

**Question**: Should I purchase new batteries for each camera? (As I still plan to use them.) Or should I look at something else? (I think that their autonomy cycles have shortened of time so that was something I was thinking to day anyway.)

**Canon-sub question**: It has also become difficult to find genuine Canon LP-E6N batteries for Canon, not sure if they are discontinued or if they are simply lost in the flow of alternative brands. What would be a good way to find them in Europe? I guess I could go to a local photography shop but I expect the price will be high. I see that LP-E6NH avec backwards compatible, thought, also more expensive. Any advice?

Edit: All batteries were re-charged a few days ago. But for some batteries, I was surprised that the charging cycles seems to be extremely short; wonder what happened.

Edit:
The Canon batteries have potentially been untouched for 1 or 2 years during the lockdowns but re-used a few times per months since September 2021 ... maybe they have been left alone between August 2022 and December 2022.

Regarding the Panasonic ones, I'm not 100% sure but I think that they have been untouched between mid-2019 and early 2022. And then untouched again until December 2022.

Comment: Thank you. I added some precision regarding the batteries "untouch times" in an edit in the question.
Regarding their purchase date, I really can't remember more precisely, I only remember that I got the 5D Mark IV shortly after it was released.

Answer (score 1):

Your batteries may have [self-discharged beyond recovery](https://hlcbattery.com/lithium-battery-over-discharge/)... or not.

Leave them in the charger for a night. If that doesn't work, they are dead, replace them. If that works, they are not dead, but potentially a bit damaged, so replace them (batteries are consumables)

I use off-brand batteries for my Canon cameras. If you don't pick the less-expensive ones, they are as good as the Canon ones.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot it so I just added this to the question: "All batteries were re-charged a few days ago. But for some betteries, I was surprised that the charging cycles seems to be extremely short, wondered what happened."

Comment: So, first option, they are dead. Personally, I recovered a battery for a 450D camera I don't use much after two years of self-discharge, but it obviously isn't back to the initial capacity. Other batteries (4 years) where definitely dead.